# How to set umbraco to accept the same email for multiple members

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have Umbraco 7.5 and I need to set the same email address for different members. How to do it?

My scenario:

I want to have different permissions for different parts (lets say sub-organization) but for a short time the contact person of 2 of those parts are the same. and it can happen again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your web config file search for `UmbracoMembershipProvider` which contains the settings for the member logins. Then set the property `requiresUniqueEmail` to false and hit save.